# Load specific css file in shortcode - wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I am making one plugin which has functionality using shortcode , While shortcode will place in the page , it will return a well desgin form 
For example : https://www.screencast.com/t/XTteV6u8qw

Now if I add bootstrap css/classes my current theme went messed up,

I want functionality like in any theme my shortcode function display design will remain same.
Any idea about how it is possible ?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This one all help you... https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the internal css of that shortcode content like below example.

```
function shortcode_func( $atts ) {

   $returnString = '<style>';
   $returnString .='#shortcode-id{background-color:yello;}';
   $returnString .= '</style>';

   $returnString .='<div id="shortcode-id"></div>';
   return $returnString;
}
```

`add_shortcode( 'shortcode-name', 'shortcode_func' );`